# php backend. front-end Angular. routing doesn't work when deployed on server

Tags: php, mysql, backend

My project is built in Angular 8, with php backend. When I deploy it locally using xampp, everything runs fine. But when I deploy it on a server, it gives me a 404 error(I tried 2 different server, one of the aws). Same when I try accessing the backend file with postman. I can see that the files in filezilla, and the path looks correct, but I still get the blasted 404 every time. any ideas? could it be a security policy issue, and if so, how do I correct it? I've attached some images showing my errors. This is my .htaccess file - I've tried editing many different ways based on SO suggestions.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

here is my login service file, which directs it to the backend:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  baseUrl = 'http://globalplantbased.com/pbcert/PB-Certification-Server/';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  // login function sends username and password and validates it
  // this function also returns token for session verification
  login(username: string, password: string, type: string): Observable<any> {
    const body = `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}login/${type}Login`, body, this.httpOptions);
  }

  register(name: string, username: string, password: string, type: string): Observable<any> {
    const body = `name=${name}&username=${username}&password=${password}`;
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}register/${type}Register`, body, this.httpOptions);
  }

  logout() {

  }
}
```

please let me know if I should add any other pictures of files. I've been working on this for many days and cannot figure it out.

this is my php login file

```
class Login extends Controller {

    private $currentModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->currentModel = $this->model('SignIn');
    }


    public function userLogin() {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $data = [
                'username' => trim($_POST['username']),
                'password' => trim($_POST['password'])
                ////trim re spaces
            ];

            //verifies username and password, returns user details true or false
            if($user = $this->currentModel->logInUser($data['username'], $data['password'])) {
                //this will return a token string on success
                if($token = $this->currentModel->setToken($user, 'user', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                    echo json_encode(['token' => $token]);

                } else {
                    echo json_encode(['error' => "login denied"]);

                }
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['error' => "login failed"]);

            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['error' => "denied"]);
        }
    }

    public function contactLogin() {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $data = [
                'username' => trim($_POST['username']),
                'password' => trim($_POST['password'])
                ////trim re spaces
            ];

            //verifies username and password, returns user details true or false
            if($user = $this->currentModel->logInContact($data['username'], $data['password'])) {
                //this will return a token string on success
                if($token = $this->currentModel->setToken($user, 'contact', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                    echo json_encode(['token' => $token]);

                } else {
                    echo json_encode(['error' => "login denied"]);

                }
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['error' => "login failed"]);

            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['error' => "denied"]);
        }


    }



}
```

and my signIn php file

```
<?php
//login contact
//login user

class SignIn {
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    //login user
    public function logInUser($username, $password) {

        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');

        $this->db->bind(':username', $username);

        //tries to get info from db
        if($row = $this->db->single()) {
            $hashed_password = $row->user_password;
            //verifies password with encryped pass from database
            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                return $row;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //login contact
    public function logInContact($username, $password) {

        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_username = :username');

        $this->db->bind(':username', $username);

        //tries to get info from db
        if($row = $this->db->single()) {
            $hashed_password = $row->contact_password;
            //verifies password with encryped pass from database
            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                return $row;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //call this function if user/contact successfully logged in
    public function setToken($id, $type, $ip) {
        try {
            //try creating random token else throw error
            if($token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32))) {
                //hashing password
                $this->db->query('INSERT INTO auth(token, ip, expiry, user_id, contact_id, company_id) VALUES (:token, :ip, NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, :userId, :contactId, :companyId)');

                $this->db->bind(':token', $token);
                $this->db->bind(':ip', $ip);

                switch ($type) {
                    case 'contact';
                    $this->db->bind('userId', null);
                    $this->db->bind('contactId', $id->contact_id);
                    $this->db->bind('companyId', $id->company_id);
                    break;
                    case 'user';
                    $this->db->bind('userId', $id->user_id);
                    $this->db->bind('contactId', null);
                        $this->db->bind('companyId', null);
                }
                //inserts token with expiry and ip to database, return token on success or false on failure
                if ($this->db->execute()) {
                    return $token;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Sorry, something went wrong! Please try again');
            }
        } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo json_encode(['error' => $error->getMessage()]);
        }
            }

    }
```

my core.php file

```
<?php
// /*
// * App Core Class
// * Creates Url and loads core controller
// * Url format - /controller/method/params
// */

class Core {
    protected $currentController = 'Home';
    protected $currentMethod = 'notFound';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
//        print_r($this->getUrl());
        $url = $this->getUrl();

//        Look in controllers for first value
        if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]) . '.php')) {
//            if exists set as controller
            $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
//            Unset 0 index
            unset($url[0]);

        }

//        Require the controller
        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->currentController . '.php';

//        Instantiate controller class
        $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

//        Check for second part of url
        if(isset($url[1])){
//            Check to see if method exists in controller
            if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
                $this->currentMethod = $url[1];

                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

//        get params
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

//        Call a callback with array of params
        call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])){
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            return $url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue here has nothing to do with Angular, and everything to do with your PHP code/Framework. Is this something you built yourself, or an existing framework? If it's an existing framework, check the documentation on how to properly build and see your routes. If it's your own code, then how do you serve your routes?

Comment: `http://globalplantbased.com/pbcert/PB-Certification-Server/login/userLogin` versus `http://globalplantbased.com/pbcert/PB-Certification-Server/Login/userLogin` ... that one L letter ;)

Comment: it's my own code, not built on any framework.  I have added the code to my login.php file(controller), as well as the signIn file(model , to give you an idea. Why does it work locally?

Comment: What code are you using to manage the routes? `/login/userLogin` is not going to automatically map to `app/controllers/Login.php:userLogin`

Comment: I've added my core.php file. I believe it contains the routing code @aynber

Comment: You need to debug this thing. The 404 is an automatic response from http server or php? If http server, then it should be some config. If PHP, where does it send this 404 response?

Comment: it's an httpErrorResponse @Felippe Duarte. I have posted an image of the console.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was my .htaccess file in /public. This is the current one and it fixed the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```